# How to increment last number in file python

Tags: python, regex, file, writefile

I have below text in the file

```
firefox-x 46.0:
google 5.1.0.1:
    - request
    - branch
```

I need to extract the last letter of first line and increase by one version and append to same file. My append part will be

```
    firefox-x 46.1:
    google 5.1.0.1:
    - request
    - branch
```

able to extract last integer but how to update and write to same file.

```
import re
with open('branch.txt','r') as fh:
 first_line = fh.readline()
 #print (first_line)
 last_number = re.findall(".*(?:\D|^)(\d+)", first_line)
 for i in last_number:
    to_int = int(i)
 #print (to_int)
 next_num = (to_int +1)
 print (next_num)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
import re
rx = r'\d+(?=:$)'
s="""firefox-x 46.0:
google 5.1.0.1:
    - request
    - branch"""

print(re.sub(rx, lambda x: str(int(x.group(0)) + 1), s, 1, re.M))
```

Output:

```
firefox-x 46.1:
google 5.1.0.1:
    - request
    - branch
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/rUN4BG)

The `\d+(?=:$)` regex with `re.M` flag will match 1+ digits that are followed with `:` at the end of a *line* and `1` passed as the *count* argument to [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) will only perform a single replacement.

The `lambda x: str(int(x.group(0)) + 1)` part will take the first match, cast the 1+ digits matched to an int, add `1` to the value and cast it back to a string.

To read and write to another file:

```
import re

rx = r'\d+(?=:$)'
with open('branch.txt', 'r') as fr:
    data = fr.read()
    with open('branch.out.txt', 'w') as fw:
        fw.write(re.sub(rx , lambda x: str(int(x.group(0)) + 1), data, 1, re.M))
```